# Font discrepancy between badge pages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, badges, fonts

When I look at the [Great Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/badges/40/great-answer) and [Great Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/badges/42/great-question) badge pages, there appears to be a significant discrepancy between the font and point used to display the question, despite it being the same question:

http://fakkelbrigade.eu/chris/images/fontdiscrepancy.png

This seems to occur over multiple badge pages -- some use one style, and some use the other. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is intentional. These aren't the same link -- the "Great Question" link links to the question, but the "Great Answer" link links to the answer; it just has the title of the question in the link because answers don't have titles. Question links and answer links are styled differently; see the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73/michael-mrozek#qpage_1-qsort_recent) and [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73/michael-mrozek#anpage_1-ansort_recent) sections of a profile

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that in practise it looks odd and nonstandardised?

Comment: The answer links look quite a bit better on a profile page since there's a style that gets rid of the bold font-weight.